# QGraphicsView cannot render video when there is a QWebEngineView

Tags: qt

I am making a very simple application which plays a video using QMediaPlayer/QGraphicsVideoItem/QGraphicsScene/QGraphicsView and in the meantime, it displays a web page using QWebEngineView.

However, when the QWebEngineView shows, only the sound of the video is played. The widget shows only white. When QWebEngineView's ->show() is not called, the video plays normally.

I've tried QVideoWidget. It doesn't have such problem.

I'm thinking that the rendering of the QGraphicsView might have conflicts with QWebEngine's.

Here's the code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QGraphicsVideoItem>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWebEngineView *webview = new QWebEngineView();
    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer();
    QGraphicsVideoItem *item = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
    QVideoWidget *vwid = new QVideoWidget();
    QGraphicsView *gview = new QGraphicsView();

    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/user/Videos/IMG_6201.MOV"));
    //player->setVideoOutput(vwid);
    player->setVideoOutput(item);
    QGraphicsScene *gscene = new QGraphicsScene();
    gview->setScene(gscene);
    webview.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com"));
    gview->scene()->addItem(item);

    //vwid->show();
    player->play();
    webview->show();
    gview->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: QGraphicsView is able to affinely transform (e.g. rotate and scale) any thing. You should not expect a video to be transformed (because your -or most- *hardware* is not powerful enough)